# How to read comma seperated values from excel and store them in a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read some comma separated values[string values] from a particular column in excel. I want to store these values as they are in a list in python.

This is the data in that column : 'a','b c','d','f,g'

When i try reading the same from excel to python, it is read as a string :
This is what it looks like : "'a','b c','d','f,g'" giving me a complete string.
I cannot split it based on ',' since my data can have ',' within it.

I just want ['a','b c','d','f,g'], how do i get this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can try this :

```
df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")
​
df["col"] = df["col"].str.strip("'").str.split("','")
```

Output :

```
print(df.iloc[0,0])
#['a', 'b c', 'd', 'f,g']

print(df)
                col
0  [a, b c, d, f,g]
```

Input used :

[image]